# setting javascript element background image to equal a download url

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

I am trying to give a javascript element a background image. This url is stored in a database and is not a string but a file path: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-firebase-182ca.appspot.com/o/images%2FScreenshot%20(2).png?alt=media&token=0edf4c43-e791-48b1-b2f4-b8ec5e65e296

I am also making a java script element, which is a div, to set its background image to this link:

```
var icon = document.createElement('img');
icon.style.cssText = "background-color: red;"
//icon.src = "'" + url + "'";
var parent = document.getElementById("loggedDisplay");
parent.appendChild(icon);
```

I havent been able to get this to work so far. How would I make this background image = the url

Comment: Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Yes, I have been working on this problem for two and a half hours as I am new to javascript.  During that time I discovered that the url was indeed a file path instead of a string. I found that escape(filepath) turns it to a string, but when I used it in my javascript: icon.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ");": i got this error: file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/WebDevStuff/'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-firebase-182ca.appspot.com/o/images%2FScreenshot%20(2).png?alt=media&token=0edf4c43-e791-48b1-b2f4-b8ec5e65e296%27 net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: yes that is the url to my image. Sorry, again im new to js, so I ask how would I use a protocol / make it so I can assing the icon the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
document.getElementById("Your div ID").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-firebase-182ca.appspot.com/o/images%2FScreenshot%20(2).png?alt=media&token=0edf4c43-e791-48b1-b2f4-b8ec5e65e296')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use style object directly too. But for css background you need to put the image url in a "url('')"

```js
function myFunction() {
  var imagePath = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-firebase-182ca.appspot.com/o/images%2FScreenshot%20(2).png?alt=media&token=0edf4c43-e791-48b1-b2f4-b8ec5e65e296";

  var icon = document.createElement('img');

  icon.style.backgroundColor = "red";

  //icon.src =  imagePath ;

  icon.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imagePath + "')";

  var parent = document.getElementById("loggedDisplay");
  parent.appendChild(icon);

}
```

```css
#loggedDisplay img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <div id="loggedDisplay"></div>

</body>

</html>
```